# JScript to Auto-Login to a Website User Account to Scrape Information

Tags: jquery, html, web, httprequest

I would like to write a script to be set with timer to auto-login into a particular property agent's account (with credentials) at a property listing website and retrieve the listings to do a reposting into their listing database. what sort of http request script should i be looking at?

Answer (score 0):

Try to capture the HTTP network traffic (using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)) that gets generated when you login using a property agent's account and post listing.

Once you have seen what HTTP requests have been made, you can try to execute an HTTP [POST](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) or GET using JQuery - depending on the requests that you have seen in Fiddler. This includes adding parameters and data into the request as well

Comment: IC. Thanks for the steps. But i'm using Mac OS. any alternative to Fiddler?